Angular - Send form on enter in MatDialog
My goal is to execute the form in a MatDialog if I press Enter. It doesn't matter which element is focused. I've searched a lot and tried lots of things but each time it didn't work.
I've tried to use ngSubmit on the form, I init the event keyup.enter on the source html element,the mat-dialog-content-Element and the form itself.
All trails didn't work. If I set the keyup.enter-Event for the form it only is triggered when I focus a form field and press enter. If I set this event to the source html-element or the mat-dialog-content-Element it only is triggered when I don't focus the form.
I tried to create a Stackblitz but it didn't work, so I am just sharing the code:
Component from which the MatDialog is opened:
TS
public openDialog() {
const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(EditUserComponent, {
  width: '100%',
  height: '100%',
});

}
HTML
<button mat-button (click)="openDialog()">Open Dialog</button>

The MatDialog that is opened:
HTML
    <div class="flex-c justify-center full-height padding-l">
  <label class="title-2">Create user</label>
  <div class="flex-c full-size padding-l gap-l">
    <div>
      <form [formGroup]="formData" class="user-form">
        <div>
          <mat-form-field>
            <mat-label>Name</mat-label>
            <input type="text" matInput formControlName="name" />
          </mat-form-field>
        </div>
        <div>
          <mat-form-field>
            <mat-label>Age</mat-label>
            <input type="number" matInput formControlName="age" />
          </mat-form-field>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
    <mat-dialog-actions>
      <button mat-button color="warn" (click)="cancel()">cancel</button>
      <button (click)="saveUser()" cdkFocusInitial>save</button>
    </mat-dialog-actions>
  </div>
</div>

TS
export class EditUserComponent {
  public formData = new FormGroup({
    name: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    age: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
  });

  constructor(public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<EditUserComponent>) {}

  public cancel() {
    this.dialogRef.close();
  }

  public save() {
    if (this.formData.valid) {
      console.log('User is updated');
    }
  }
}

How can I do that?

Have you tried using @HostListener? HostListener allows you to capture events inside the component. Something like this
export class EditUserComponent {
  public formData = new FormGroup({
    name: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    age: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
  });

  constructor(public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<EditUserComponent>) {}

  @HostListener('document:keydown', ['$event'])
  handleKeyboardEvent(event: KeyboardEvent) {
    if (event.key === 'Enter') {
      this.save();
    }
  }

  public cancel() {
    this.dialogRef.close();
  }

  public save() {
    if (this.formData.valid) {
      console.log('User is updated');
    }
  }
}


Thanks for you answer. I already found some posts about using the HostListener too, but the thing is that I execute in every DialogComponent another save-functionality and if I would do that with a directive I have to pass all data into the directive. That's the reason why I don't use it.

Subscribe to the dialogRef and pass the form data back in afterClosed (reject close if form invalid), then the calling component, and not the dialog, can programmatically handle the save (all other close options can pass false). If you want to keep the save logic independent consider implementing a dialog service.

@Stefan, That wasn't mentioned in question. Anyways if you are using common DialogComponent then You need to pass Flag like closeOnEnter= true something like this. And that's not a bad practice, it's just configuration. By default, you can keep it false so that you don't need to pass when you don't require it.

btw who gave me -1? -_- ... I just had 21 reputations and now someone gave -1 without commenting on why...

Thank you hachi :) I didn't know that I can use the HostListener in a component too.

You just have to pass values of your form when you close your dialog here
export class EditUserComponent {
  public formData = new FormGroup({
    name: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    age: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
  });

  constructor(public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<EditUserComponent>) {}

  public cancel() {
    this.dialogRef.close();
  }

  public save() {
    if (this.formData.valid) {
      console.log('User is updated');
      this.dialogRef.close(this.formData.values);
    }
  }
}

And subscribe to close observable in the component where you call dialog.open()
public openDialog() {
const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(EditUserComponent, {
  width: '100%',
  height: '100%',
});

dialogRef.close.pipe(tap(values => saveForm(values)), takeUntilDestroy(this.destroyRef)).subscribe()
}

